# pandas long (very long + index) to wide format conversion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a single column within a dataframe which comprises both the index (virus) and the data to tabulate and wish to convert to wide format.

**Input data**

```
virus1
AGCTGAGTGAG # sequence
40.1 # score 1
23 # score 2
102 # score 3
virus2
AGCTGAGTGAG # sequence
43.4 # score 1
32 # score 2
101 # score 3
virus3
AGTTGAGTGAG # sequence
41.3 # score 1
35 # score 2
100 # score 3
.... >100 inputs
```

**Dataframe output**

```
       sequence     score1 score2 score3
virus1 AGCTGAGTGAG  40.1   43.4   41.3
virus2 AGCTGAGTGAG  23     32     35
virus3 AGTTGAGTGAG  102    101    100
```

I attempted to import the data into a single dataframe and move the rows into columns of a new dataframe

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None)
index_labels = df.iloc[::4].astype(str)
dfvirus = pd.DataFrame(index=labels)
dfvirus['sequence'] = df.iloc[1::5].astype(str)
dfvirus['score1'] = df.iloc[2::5].astype(float)
dfvirus['score2'] = df.iloc[3::5].astype(int)
dfvirus['score3'] = df.iloc[4::5].astype(int)
```

The above didn't work I get NaN or nan for the values of e.g. `dfvirus['sequence'].head()` depending on whether the input is a number or a string. I could do this by constructing a hierarchical index, but that would mean looping a very long index into a `list`.

Moving from long to wide format is a common issue and I would be grateful if you could show a simpler solution or where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,5), 
                      columns=['virus','sequence','score1','score2','score3']
                     )
```

Output

```
    virus      sequence score1 score2 score3
0  virus1   AGCTGAGTGAG   40.1     23    102 
1  virus2   AGCTGAGTGAG   43.4     32    101 
2  virus3   AGTTGAGTGAG   41.3     35    100
```

Comment: Cool, I am not exactly sure how the `-1` part works, but yet this works well. Thank you